# VBA interop with Excel-DNA

Tags: excel-dna

I am trying to implement Excel-DNA addin which can be called from VBA.

I am following [Integrating with VBA](https://docs.excel-dna.net/integrating-with-vba/)

But the `ExcelDna.Integration.CustomUI.ExcelComAddIn` throw `ExcelComAddIn` is not available under `ExcelDna.Integration.CustomUI`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best example of exposing classes from your Excel-DNA project to VBA is this one: https://github.com/Excel-DNA/Samples/tree/master/ComServerVB

The best place to ask questions about Excel-DNA is the Google Group here: https://groups.google.com/g/exceldna